# ViewDidLoad method in UIViewController - when does it get called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` called LaunchController that is launched in my iPhone app when the app first opens:

```
@interface LaunchController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Then, when a button is clicked, I push another view controller:

```
 MainController *c = [[MainController alloc] initWithImage:image];
 [self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
```

MainController has the following constructor, which I use:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        image = img;
        NSLog(@"inited the image");
    }

    return self;
}
```

and then it has a viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"calling view did load");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    NSLog(@"displaying main controller");
}
```

When the program runs, I see that the constructor for `MainController` is called (due to the output of `NSLog`), however `viewDidLoad` never gets called, even though I am calling `presentModalViewController`. Why is this? Why isn't `viewDidLoad` being called?

Comment: Does MainController have a `loadView` method implemented?

Comment: No. What should go in loadView?

Comment: You don't actually check it if the new view was initiated. Move NSLog within the if-brackets to see if the view was initiated.

Comment: yes, it was inited. I moved it and it still prints it.

Comment: Do you have a nib named `MainController.xib` in your project? If you don't, you must override `-loadView` and provide an empty view.

Comment: Related, if you aren't using nibs :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876212/proper-use-of-loadview-and-viewdidload-with-uiviewcontroller-without-nibs-xibs

Comment: that link doesn't provide an answer, just another problem. and @JasonCoco, no I don't have a nib. How can I overwrite loadView such that viewDidLoad will be called

Comment: I'm not actually sure it's your problem, but you can just override `-loadView` and create a view and assign it to `self.view`. Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I'm not sure. What's a storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is something as followings. When you need the property of `view` inside UIViewController, it will be loaded with lazy manner.

```
- (UIView *)view 
{
   if (_view == nil) {
      [self loadView]; //< or, the view is loaded from xib, or something else.
      [self viewDidLoad];
   }

   return _view;
}
```

After the `view` initialized, it will call `viewDidLoad` to inform the `UIViewController`.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Apple documentation specifically states that loadView and viewDidLoad should not be called directly.  From `loadView`: "You should never call this method directly."

Comment: @amattn: You are right. But I just use above codes to describe when the `-viewDidLoad` called.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't loading your view controller from a xib file, and from comments you don't have anything in loadView (which is where you would create your view controller's view if you were not using a xib file).

Therefore, your view isn't being loaded, so viewDidLoad is never called.

Typically you would use `initWithNibName:` to initialise a new view controller, and then set the image after it (so expose the image as a property).

viewDidLoad will be called as soon as your controller's view property is accessed, that is when you display it for the first time or request it (e.g. have some code that calls `c.view`.

Comment: but I'm not using xib or initWithNib

Comment: That would have been useful information to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason viewDidLoad is not being called is because you aren't loading a view.

In your init method:

```
 self = [super init];
```

means that you are just creating a naked view from scratch.  not loading one from a nib.

try this instead:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

If you have a xib or nib file with the same name as the view controller class it should find if.  Otherwise, you can just give a nibName that works.

UPDATE:

If you are not using nib files, then the appropriate method is NOT viewDidLoad.  You have to implement `loadView` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

In your specific case, just put everything that is currently in viewDidLoad into loadView.

Comment: But I'm not using nib, I want to create the view programatically.

Comment: updated.  Read the documentation for UIViewController for more specifics about loadView.